# How to set maximum & minimum limits to date picker?

Tags: android, max, min, android-datepicker

I am using date picker in my application couples of time. I want my date picker to show dates following some restrictions. I am using the below code:-

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_DIALOG:
                datePickerDialogDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate) {
                        year = selectedYear;
                        month = selectedMonth;
                        date = selectedDate;

                        activitySignUpDateEditText.setText(new StringBuilder().append(date));
                        activitySignUpMonthEditText.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1));
                        activitySignUpYearEditText.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year));
                    }
                };

                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerDialogDateSetListener, year, month, date);

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Somewhere i want the date picker to show maximum date 18 years back from current date & somewhere minimum date as the current date. I have searched a lot but doesn't found any satisfactory answer. I know about setMaxDate() & setMinDate() methods of date picker but when i tried with it, i am unable to set selected date on my edit text. any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing this line:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
```

By those:

```
DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
DatePicker datePicker = dpDialog.getDatePicker();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//get the current day
datePicker.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//set the current day as the max date
return dpDialog;
```

in the same way you set the minimum date as well

```
DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
DatePicker datePicker = dpDialog.getDatePicker();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//get the current day
datePicker.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//set the current day as the max date
return dpDialog;
```

Comment: what is pyear, pmonth & pday here

Comment: i am able set lower limit but unable to set maximum limit 18 years back from current date.

Answer (score 1):

For setting Max date as 18 years back, the following code snippet will do the job:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year - 18, month, day);

//For setting minimum date as Current Date
//dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis ());

//For setting maximum date as 18 years back
c.set(year - 18, month, day);
dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
return dateDialog;
```

As MaxDate can't be less than MinDate thus, MinDate should not be set as current date when MaxDate is set as 18 years back.

Hope it'll work for you.